# How to test function inside react context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

iam having trouble with covering function inside react context
Before that, let me show you the snippet of the code

```
import {
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  createContext,
  ReactNode,
  FC
} from 'react';
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { pushBackRoute } from '../libs/helpers/backRouteHelper';
 
export interface BottomBarProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}
 
export interface IBottomBarProvider {
  selectedMenu: string;
  handleClickMenu: (item: { name: string; route: string }) => void;
}
 
export const defaultValueBottomBarContext = {
  selectedMenu: '',
  handleClickMenu: () => {}
};
 
export const BottomBarContext = createContext<IBottomBarProvider>(
  defaultValueBottomBarContext
);
 
export const BottomBarProvider: FC<BottomBarProviderProps> = ({
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();
  const [selectedMenu, setSelectedMenu] = useState('Belanja');
 
  const handleClickMenu = useCallback(
    (item) => {
      setSelectedMenu(item.name);
      pushBackRoute(location.pathname);
      history.push(item.route);
    },
    [selectedMenu, location?.pathname]
  );
 
  useEffect(() => {
    Iif (location.pathname === '/marketplace/history') {
      setSelectedMenu('Riwayat');
    }
  }, [location.pathname]);
 
  const value: IBottomBarProvider = {
    selectedMenu,
    handleClickMenu
  };
 
  return (
    <BottomBarContext.Provider
      value={value}
      {...props}
      data-testid="bottom-bar-context"
    >
      {children}
    </BottomBarContext.Provider>
  );
};
 
BottomBarProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node
};
 
BottomBarProvider.defaultProps = {
  children: null
};
```

So i managed to cover most of the hooks and render, but the function/handle function inside this context is really hard

[image]

And this is my current test code, below :

```
/* eslint-disable jest/prefer-called-with */
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BottomBarProvider } from './BottomBarContext';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

const mockHistoryPush = jest.fn();
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useLocation: () => ({
    pathname: '/marketplace'
  }),
  useHistory: () => ({
    push: mockHistoryPush
  })
}));
describe('BottomBarProvider', () => {
  it('should render the children and update the selected menu when handleClickMenu is called', () => {
    //Arrange
    const children = <div data-testid="children">Hello, World!</div>;
    //Act
    render(<BottomBarProvider>{children}</BottomBarProvider>);
    //Assert
    expect(screen.getByTestId('children')).toHaveTextContent('Hello, World!');
  });
});
```

Do you guys have any idea how to cover the function inside this context ?

Comment: Render a child inside the provider, set the child's `onClick` the `handleClickMenu` and click it. The test should make sure the `push` has been called by `expect(mockHistoryPush).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Comment: I already tried that, by mocking the `handleClickMenu` to jest.fn(), but it still not covered @MoshFeu

Comment: It's not enough to just assign `handleClickMenu` to a mock function, it's just a setup. You should add a test the expects that this function has been called.

Answer (score 1):

Mock functions, hooks, and components of the module you don't own are not recommended. The `useLocation` and `useHistory` hooks in your case. Incorrect mock will break their functions which causes your tests to pass based on incorrect mock implementation.

Use [`<MemoryRouter/>`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/MemoryRouter) component for testing history change. See [official example of RTL](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/) about how to test react router

You should also create a test component to consume the React Context for testing the `<BottomBarProvider/>` component and `BottomBarContext`. The key is to trigger the `handleClickMenu` event handler by firing a click event on some element of the test component.

E.g.

`BottomBarContext.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  createContext,
  ReactNode,
  FC
} from 'react';
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
// import { pushBackRoute } from '../libs/helpers/backRouteHelper';

export interface BottomBarProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export interface IBottomBarProvider {
  selectedMenu: string;
  handleClickMenu: (item: { name: string; route: string }) => void;
}

export const defaultValueBottomBarContext = {
  selectedMenu: '',
  handleClickMenu: () => { }
};

export const BottomBarContext = createContext<IBottomBarProvider>(
  defaultValueBottomBarContext
);

export const BottomBarProvider: FC<BottomBarProviderProps> = ({
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();
  const [selectedMenu, setSelectedMenu] = useState('Belanja');

  const handleClickMenu = useCallback(
    (item) => {
      setSelectedMenu(item.name);
      // pushBackRoute(location.pathname);
      history.push(item.route);
    },
    [selectedMenu, location?.pathname]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname === '/marketplace/history') {
      setSelectedMenu('Riwayat');
    }
  }, [location.pathname]);

  const value: IBottomBarProvider = {
    selectedMenu,
    handleClickMenu
  };

  return (
    <BottomBarContext.Provider value={value} {...props} data-testid="bottom-bar-context">
      {children}
    </BottomBarContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

`BottomBarContext.test.tsx`:

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BottomBarContext, BottomBarProvider } from './BottomBarContext';

describe('BottomBarProvider', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const TestComp = () => {
      const bottomBarContext = useContext(BottomBarContext);
      const menuItems = [
        { name: 'a', route: '/a' },
        { name: 'b', route: '/b' },
      ];
      return (
        <>
          <ul>
            {menuItems.map((item) => (
              <li key={item.route} onClick={() => bottomBarContext.handleClickMenu(item)}>
                {item.name}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          <p>selected menu: {bottomBarContext.selectedMenu}</p>
          <Switch>
            {menuItems.map((item) => (
              <Route key={item.route} path={item.route} component={() => <div>{item.name} component</div>} />
            ))}
          </Switch>
        </>
      );
    };
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
        <BottomBarProvider>
          <TestComp />
        </BottomBarProvider>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    const firstListItem = screen.getAllByRole('listitem')[0];
    fireEvent.click(firstListItem);
    expect(screen.getByText('selected menu: a')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('a component')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/74931928/BottomBarContext.test.tsx (16.574 s)
  BottomBarProvider
    ✓ should pass (116 ms)

----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                  | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files             |      95 |    66.67 |      75 |   94.74 |                   
 BottomBarContext.tsx |      95 |    66.67 |      75 |   94.74 | 50                
----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        18.184 s, estimated 23 s
```

Coverage HTML reporter:

[image]

Comment: Hi, i got an error like this `TypeError: history.createMemoryHistory is not a function`. do you know why is it ?